# Cordova fcm plugin: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer

Tags: android, firebase, cordova

I want to enable push notifications using Firebase in Cordova app. I have created a new firebase project in their console and added both Android and iOS apps. Downloaded the keys, placed them in the Cordova's root directory and then ran the command to install the fcm plugin: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm`.

Then I try to prepare or build and getting the next error (for both Android and iOS):

```
cordova prepare ios
The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Error
```

I am using:

```
Installed platforms:
  android 8.1.0
  ios 5.1.1
Available platforms: 
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^1.0.0
  osx ^5.0.0
  windows ^7.0.0

Cordova version: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

Comment: have you got the solutions?

Comment: Yes see my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the new fork of this plugin, install this instead - fixes all issues:

[cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated)